# MFC Feature Pack Upgrade - CMFCAutoHideBar appears beneath ribbon

Tags: mfc, ribbon, mfc-feature-pack

I'm working on upgrading an older MFC/C++ application to use the MFC Feature Pack upgrades.

I've swapped out the old toolbar/menu for a ribbon, and found that if using the autohide feature of the `CDockablePanes`, the resulting `CMFCAutoHideBar` stretches the entire span of the app window and is overlapped by the top-most bar of the ribbon.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Please remove all stored settings in the registry first and recheck the issue. It may be that the changes to your code leads into some incompatibilities with the stored window positions.

Comment: Sadly, wiping the registry didn't help any

Comment: I figured the issue out...